# except query in knex.js

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to insert a subquery on table b into table a. Many of the records in the subquery will already be in table a. the idiomatic way to do this in postgres would seem to be to use an `EXCEPT` query. However, I can't find knex support for that (other than raw). Is there a way to do `EXCEPT` queries that I missed? I know I could join on a in the subquery and do `WHERE NOT IN`, but that seems likely to be significantly slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way to check [existence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-subquery.html) in postgres is `where exists/not exists` as far as I can remember.

This can be easily done with `knex`

```
const knex = require('knex')({ client: 'pg' })

const builder = knex('table_name')
    .insert((sub) => {
        sub.select('*').from('another_table').whereNotExists((existsBuilder) => {
            existsBuilder
                .select('*')
                .from('table_name')
                .whereRaw('table_name.id = another_table.id')
        })
    })

console.log(builder.toString())
// => insert into "table_name" select * from "another_table" where not exists (select * from "table_name" where table_name.id = another_table.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually postgresql optimizes your `not in (subquery)` to be equal with `except` statement.

Knex does not have any special support for `EXCEPT` query, so if you like to use it, then you indeed need to do something like:

```
knex.raw(`? EXCEPT ?`, [query1, query2])
```

If you are worried about performance differences I recommend trying to check query plans for both ways of doing the query (EXPLAIN query) and see if there are any differences how pg internally executes them.